# Is it neccessary to uninstall previous version of any s/w before upgrading to a new version

Tags: windows

Like system drivers, is it necessary to uninstall previous version of any software before upgrading to a new version?

Comment: This depends entirely on the software and how it is written or installed. This question cannot be answered definitively for all software.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the software.

Some are designed to update and require a previous version to be installed.

Some software may be a totally fresh build and as such do not require the previous version. However, it may (or may not) conflict with other versions. Or, it may let you run 2 versions side by side.

Some software will remove previous versions automatically.

It really is up to the software vendor.

Comment: always read the manual :)